# BVP Find values of L > 0 if possible

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Determine whether it is possible to find values of $L > 0$ so that the given boundary-value problem has precisely one nontrivial solution, more than one solution, no solution, and the trivial solution. (Let $k$ represent an arbitrary integer. If an answer does not exist, enter $\textrm{DNE}$)
>   $$
> y'' + 16y = 0,\quad  y(0) = 1,\quad  y(L) = 1
> $$
>
> - (a) precisely one nontrivial solution $L =$
> - (b) more than one solution $L =$
> - (c) no solution $L =$
> - (d) the trivial solution $L =$

I'm not entirely sure how to proceed here but I used a characteristic equation to get:
$$y = c_1\cos4x + c_2\sin4x$$ and plugging in the values: 
$$y = \cos4x + 1 - \cos4L$$ (not sure if it would help me since I assume somehow I'm supposed to make this into an eigenvalue/function)

I'm stuck here and not sure what to do.. If I set the solution to zero it would give me $$L = \cos^{-1}(\cos(4x) + 1)/ 4$$ which I suppose wouldn't be trivial but I'm not sure about the rest.

Any help would be appreciated :) (please lol)

Answer (score 1):

I do not see how your second equation relates to the solution of the boundary conditions
\begin{align}
1&=c_1,\\
1&=c_1\cos4L+c_2\sin4L,\\
\implies c_2&=\frac{1-\cos4L}{\sin4L}=\tan2L.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

The boundary conditions give
$$ c_1 = 1 $$
$$ c_1 \cos 4L + c_2\sin 4L = 1 $$

First of all, since $c_1 = 1$, the trivial solution $y(x) = 0$ can never occur

Let's examine the second equation

If $ \sin 4L \ne 0 $, there exists one unique solution for $c_2$ 
$$ c_2 = \frac{1-\cos4L}{\sin 4L} $$

and therefore one unique (non-trivial) solution for $y(x)$

If $ \sin 4L = 0 $, then $ \cos 4L = \pm 1 $, giving two cases:

- If $\cos 4L = 1$, we get $c_1 = 1$ again and no limitations for $c_2$, meaning there are infinitely many solutions
- If $\cos 4L = -1$, then $c_1 = -1$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, no solution exists for this case.

To recap:

- One solution: $\sin 4L \ne 0$
- More than one solution: $\cos 4L = 1$
- No solution: $\cos 4L = -1$
- Trivial solution: Never

You can figure out yourself which values of $L$ satisfy these cases, but that's the gist of it.